# Why does Java allow nested method calls without importing the class?

Tags: java

This is something that we all take for granted, but the thought occurred to me today. Why can we do this?

```
package com.package


public class SomeOtherClass{

    private ClassContainingList classContainingList = new ClassContainingList();

    public void doStuff(){
        SomeClass someClass = classContainingList.getList().get(0);  
    }
}
```

Assume that `ClassContainingList` and `SomeClass` are also in `com.package` and `classContainingList.getList()` returns a `java.util.List`.

In `classContainingList.getList().get(0)` we are now calling methods from the `List` interface without ever actually importing it.

How does Java "know" about the method without an import?

Comment: Intuitively, I would think `getList()` would return a `java.util.List` making the import unnecessary, but I'd like to know for sure.

Comment: `import` statements, as the duplicate post explains, simply allow you to refer to types with their short name. Since you don't need to refer to any type by name here, an `import` is not necessary.